# How to identify that the messages have stopped coming in serial port using ttl-teraterm

Tags: macros, ttl, teraterm

I am trying to close teraterm using ttl script, if the last message was received 10 seconds back. How to identify that the messages have stopped coming in the port?

Answer (score 1):

Add below code at the end of your script

pause 10

disconnect 0

end

Comment: Thanks.. but I needed a little more help, I actually also need a command line to find out, if the message has stopped coming first, before waiting for 10 seconds